# How do I silently print an iframe in IE11?

Tags: javascript, html, activex, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to print silently as part of a kiosk web app. So far I can print an iframe with user confirmation, and I can print the entire page silently, but I am unable to print just the iframe silently. I only need this to work in IE11, so ActiveX controls are available to me. Here is the minimal example I have so far:

testcase.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>a</p>
    <iframe id="print-frame" src="testcaseiframe.html"></iframe>
</html>
```

testcaseiframe.html (1) (Prints iframe with user confirmation)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/javascript">
        function selfPrint(){
            self.focus();
            self.print();
        }
        setTimeout('selfPrint()',0);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Iframe</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

testcaseiframe.html (2) (Prints entire page silently)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/javascript">
        setTimeout(function print() {
            PrintCommandObject.ExecWB(6, 2);
            PrintCommandObject.outerHTML = "";
        },0);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Iframe</p>
        <object ID="PrintCommandObject" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

To run, use the npm serve package and open in IE11 after the site has been added to 'Trusted Sites' and ActiveX controls, even unsigned ones, have been enabled.

I've spent a lot of time on StackOverflow and I think that the issue may just be that the ActiveX control does not support printing from an iframe. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: An idea, I would try to copy-paste the content of the iframe to a popup window (without giving a focus to it), than I would call self.print on window.onload and finally close the popup window.